# how to maintain session for login form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session

```
app.controller('loginController',function($scope,$http, $window){
//  console.log(1);
    $scope.adminLogin = function() {
        alert("aaaaaa");
        var username=$scope.username;
        var password=$scope.password;
        if(username=="admin@admin.com" && password=="admin123")
        {

            window.location = '/PricePredictionUI/#/DASHBOARD';

        }
        else
        {
            $scope.message="Error";
            $scope.messagecolor="alert alert-danger";
        }

        //window.location = '/PricePredictionUI/#/DASHBOARD';


        };
});
```

above is my login controller.
I am pretty new to angularjs. 
I am able to login and land on new page
Now I need to maintain session for my login form.
how to do it?

Comment: what session? if you are using hard coded name and passowrd you clearly aren't logging in through server which is the only safe way to do authorization and where session state would reside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correct, you need the authentication to persist even when you close the tab and reopen it later.

Short answer :- Use [window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Create a token on a successful login attempt, save it in the localstorage and check for each time the page loads.

Long - Short Answer :- This does not involve hardcoding the user creds. Look-up for stateless authentication like JWT or Cookie based solutions. These invovle serverside token/cookie getting created, passed through your REST - service headers and persisted in the local storage of the browser. I personally like JWT because it has less overhead.

Hope that helps!

Edit :- Updating that piece of code a bit. Might have typos. Try to use UI-Router instead of windows redirect.

```
app.controller('loginController',['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http){
    //Check if localStorage contains authToken
    (window.localStorage.getItem('authToken') == 'success')? 'redirect - to - your page ' : 'Go - to - login';
    $scope.adminLogin = function() {
        if($scope.username=="admin@admin.com" && $scope.password=="admin123"){
          window.localStorage.setItem('authToken', 'success');       
          window.location = '/PricePredictionUI/#/DASHBOARD';

        }else{
            $scope.message="Error";
            $scope.messagecolor="alert alert-danger";
        }    
     };
}]);
```